# Merging multiple excel files

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to read multiple excel files with in R studio so I can append them to one large dataset. For some reason it is not uploading any of the excel files. I have the correct working directory but the R file is always empty.

The name of the files are sbir_award_1 sbir_award_2 , etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
sbir <- list.files(pattern = "data/raw/sbir/sbir_award_.xlsx")
data <- list()                                                    

df.list <- lapply(file.list,read.xlsx)
```

Comment: What's the `file.list` that you use in the last line here? Is this defined somewhere else in your script?

Comment: Also, `read.xlsx` should be `read_xlsx` with an underscore

Comment: @slothrop I do not have a file.list defined. I thought the list.files takes care of this?

Comment: In your code, you're using `list.files` to populate a variable called `sbir`.  So if those are the files you want, then you can use `sbir` instead of `file.list` in the last line.  However, have you checked whether `sbir` contains the right files? That pattern looks like it won't match your example filenames.

Comment: I am trying to populate the entire excel file I have 78 excel files I need to append to one master. @slothrop

Comment: Right - and if your files have names like 'sbir_award_1.xlsx', the pattern you have won't match them. Try something like `sbir <- list.files(path="data/raw/sbir", pattern="sbir_award_\\d+.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)`